# RDA correlation triplot with vegan

Tags: r, vegan, rda, triplot

I am trying to plot an RDA correlation triplot (using plot(rda_model)) using the vegan package in R, however I am confused about which 'scaling' to use.

In Zuur (2007, Analysing Ecological Data), `scaling` refers to the power of the diagonal matrix containing the square root of the eigenvalues and states that for the correlation triplot scaling=2. However, Jari Oksanen (Design decisions and implementation details in vegan) uses this term (when using plot(rda)) for scaling either sites or species by the eigenvalues.

I would really appreiate advice on how to do a correlation triplot- whichever thing `scaling` refers to.

```
M1=rda(SPECr~.,data = CHEMr,scale=TRUE)

summary(M1)

plot(M1,main="Correlation triplot",cex=1.1,scaling=2)#is this correct?

var.scall=scores(M1,choices=1:2,display="sp",scaling=2)

arrows(0,0,var.scall[,1],var.scall[,2],length=0,lty=1,col="red")
```

Comment: He's Zuur (with two 'u's and one 'r'). The meaning of the 'scaling' parameter in vegan is similar as in CANOCO 3 and in ter Braak's articles. Somehow I think that Zuur's description is similar to CANOCO & vegan and different from your description, but I haven't seen the book (too expensive).

Comment: Thanks for the advice (and for pointing out the typo)!

Comment: In recent vegan, you can choose correlation-based scores for the plot you want by specifying `correlation = TRUE` with `scaling = “sites”`, or `”species”` or “`symmetric”` depending on what you want to focus on. IIRC, the correlation-based score were negative values in Canoco-speak. In CCA you use `hill = TRUE` rather than `correlation = TRUE`.